# How would I have a field updated sequentially based on a defined where clause order

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to update a field sequentially based on the order that it was put in the where in ('[john2].[john2]','[john3].[john3]','[john].[john]') clause but it does not appear to update based on its associated order (see SQL below).
 How would I have a field updated sequentially based on a pre-defined where clause order?

John

```
drop sequence temp_seq;
 create temp sequence temp_seq;

update gis_field_configuration_bycube
 set seq_in_grid = nextval('temp_seq')
 where cube = 'Instruments' and level_unique_name in ('[john2].[john2]','[john3].[john3]','[john].[john]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is irrelevant in an IN() construct because it defines a set, not a list of values in a strict sense.
The `VALUES` clause is what should be used instead.

Also, assuming Postgres 8.4 or better, `row_number()` would be less cumbersome than creating a temporary sequence.

Here's what should work:

```
update gis_field_configuration_bycube
 set seq_in_grid = rn
from 
(select  row_number() over () as rn , string from
  (values ('[john2].[john2]'),('[john3].[john3]'),('[john].[john]')) as v(string)
) as subquery
 where cube = 'Instruments'
 and level_unique_name=subquery.string;
```

Comment: I got the above to work within a postgres SQL window but since the data is not hardcoded like the basic example that you used to create the above it is much more difficult when the data vary from a program and I am having difficulty getting it to work when I have a variable assigned containing something like:

Comment: I got the above to work within a postgres SQL window but since the data is not hardcoded like the basic example that you used to create the above it is much more difficult when the data vary from a program and I am having difficulty getting it to work when I have a variable assigned containing something like:

Comment: I got the above to work SQL window but since the data is not hardcoded like the basic example that you used to create the above it is much more difficult when the data vary from a program and I am having difficulty getting it to work when I have a variable = "('[john2].[john2]'),('[john3].[john3]'),('[john].[john]')" assigned containing something like: update gis_field_configuration_bycube 
 set seq_in_grid = rn 
from  
(select  row_number() over () as rn , string from 
  (values variable) as v(string) 
) as subquery 
 where cube = 'Instruments' 
 and level_unique_name=subquery.string;

Comment: @JohnMitchell: update your question with details on how your variable comes into the query (don't use comments for this, there's not enough space in comments).

Comment: @JohnMitchell: it is your question that you should update, not my answer. I tried to move your update into the question, but my first try somehow failed and now it seems to be lost. Anyway, I think you should make it a second different question which would be like: how to properly inject or submit a variable list of values into a SQL statement given the client API you're using (.NET npgsql?). Having the right SQL construct and how to interface it with the client-side   are really two different problems that may be answered by different people.